# Bar magnet dropped through wire loop

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

I was wondering how an emf versus time graph for this situation will change if the distance from which the bar magnet is released decreases? Many thanks

Comment: Isn't this just the same as asking what happens if you change the speed that you move the magnet through the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Since all that happened is that the velocity is higher, the rate of change of flux will be higher i.e the graph as a whole will be scaled. So, the initial flux change is 0 as it is barely moving but as it gets closer and gains more velocity flux increases quicker i.e magnitude of emf is higher

Comment: How is the right-hand rule used in the above scenario given the magnetic field and the velocity are in the same direction (which would make the cross product 0)